# How to load ActiveRecord in rails but skip connecting to a database when starting the app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm trying to build an app that connects to a database on a per session basis, based on the connection string the user provides.  I'm thinking of doing this as a filter in ApplicationController.

Thing is, my app still tries to load up database.yml when I start the server or even when I run a generator.  How do I skip this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you could use this [null-db adapter](https://github.com/woodie/activerecord-nulldb-adapter). It's simply an adapter that does nothing.